# Can interface be not abstract?

Tags: object-oriented, interfaces

Friend of mine said that not every interface is abstract. I haven't chance to discuss that with him but it get me thinking of not abstract interface in any type of language.

Is there a non abstract interfaces?

Comment: No, it's the other way around : not every abstract class is an interface.

Comment: Are you talking about an "interface" as in a C# interface?  Or do you mean the more generic form, like "the steering wheel and pedals in your car are an interface"?

Comment: interface like in interface in C#, C++, Delphi, Java and all the others oop languages

Comment: Java 8 introduced interfaces with default [implementations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857832/are-defaults-in-jdk-8-a-form-of-multiple-inheritance-in-java). So you may have interface that is not-abstract, i.e., have all methods implemented in a default way.

Comment: It depends on what your friend means by "interface". Anything that can be used has an interface whether it's concrete or abstract. A concrete Chair has an interface where you sit in it.  But if he means the c# keyword then he is wrong, as that's always abstract. If he designs his own language that allows him to use the interface keyword that way then he is correct.

Comment: Interfaces cannot be instantiated. Ergo they are abstract.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple answer to your question : No, your friend is wrong.

An interface provides no implementation of the methods it defines. Would it make sense if we could instantiate one of those? Of course not. Interfaces are only that, an abstraction.

This is obviously assuming that when you say `interface`, you think about the interface language feature as defined by C#, Java, C++, etc with the `interface` keyword. In the case your friend means an API interface, then the question does not really make sense to me. APIs may allow you to extend functionality through subclassing or by adhering to a particular contract as defined by an interface or an existing class of the system.

Comment: An API is an _interface_. I'm pretty sure they usually provide concrete methods

Comment: @Useless - as JustMe answered in a comment on the original question, he/she specifically means "interface" in the technical sense within a language like C#, not in the sense of an "API".

Comment: What about interface in sens of an "API"?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

The *idea of an interface* (ie, a description of facilities provided and their semantics) is inherently abstract.

However, the question appears to confuse this with the mechanism by which such an interface (small *i*) may be reified into certain languages which provide an `Interface` (big *i*) for this purpose.

Further, there is anyway more than one thing you may wish abstract:

- polymorphism: you wish to hide multiple different types or behaviours behind a description of the things they have in common. In this case, the interface should be *probably* abstract
- implementation: you wish to hide the details of a complex system behind a unifying abstraction. In this case there may never be more than one implementation, so the interface can itself be concrete

Comment: I don't think neither things you describe can be called an interface.

Comment: Case 1 is an Abstract Base Class, which is reified in several languages as something called an Interface. Case 2 is something like an Application Programming Interface

Comment: This is correct. However I get a feeling the question is about class interfaces, which technically can't be non abstract, so perhaps you should clarify in your answer that although the general notion of interface can be non abstract, the class interface structure can't. (you already mention all this, just make the distinction between concept and structure a bit clearer)

Comment: Java 8 introduced interfaces with default [implementations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857832/are-defaults-in-jdk-8-a-form-of-multiple-inheritance-in-java). So you may have interface that is not-abstract, i.e., have all methods implemented in a default way.

Answer (score 2):

Depends much on what meaning your friend gave to the word **interface**.

### Interface as the concept of an abstract contract on methods/properties

---

So this means the Interface types provided by diverse languages (like the
cited above: C#, Object Pascal (Delphi or FPC), Java, etc) **so the answer is no.**

In this case, the Interface is an contract on methods - without any form of implementation.

### Interface as a contract on the description of facilities provided and their semantics

---

In this case, even an non-pure abstract class can be considered an interface. In this case, the designer even have how to implement default basic behavior (like throwing exceptions on non-implemented virtual methods which are not abstract) on that base class.

So, if it is the case, **so yes those "interfaces" can be not abstract.**

Answer (score 1):

No.

Interface from simple definition is abstraction of API that class can implement. If it is not abstract, then it is not an interface.

Comment: So how would you call interfaces in Java 8 with default implementation? Java 8 introduced interfaces with default [implementations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857832/are-defaults-in-jdk-8-a-form-of-multiple-inheritance-in-java). So you may have interface that is not-abstract, i.e., have all methods implemented in a default way.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces need not be abstract. Example:

```
class Foo {
public:
    void printHello () {
         printf("Hello");
    }
};
```

Here `Foo` is a concrete class with an interface `printHello()`. `Foo` is not abstract.

Answer (score 1):

All above answers are correct. But this is how I understand it.

`Interface` are just definitions of service. E.g. You need to book a ticket for an air travel. Its an idea/concept that you 'book a ticket'. And not worry about how it is done physically.

A `Class` that implements it will define how it is done and what physical form it takes.

E.g. An Interface could be to book a ticket. You could then have various entities that provide you this service. A travel agent, online booking, or actual airline office. 
 They all provide the service (`Interface`) to book a ticket.